# Cookie Cutter for Text Box Creation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, smartobject

I have a design where I am adding text on top of butterflies. I have been using [this technique](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photoshop-text/text-effects/text-wrap/) to create a custom text box shape. Although given the complex shaping of the butterflies this is taking some time and as they are all different shapes I cannot simply duplicate the text boxes.

My question is: Is there a way to use the underlying Smart Object as a sort of "cookie cutter" to intersect the over laying path and create the shape in one "or two" clicks?

[image: cookie cutter in photoshop]

Comment: If the butterfly was created in Illustrator, you could pretty easily create your custom-shaped text box in there and then copy/paste said path into Photoshop. If interested in hearing more, I could reply with more details.

Comment: @mhulse It is an illustrator file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this one out myself. Here is the solution.

1. Ctrl (Cmd) + Click the "Smart Object Thumbnail" in the Layers tab.

   This will give you a "Marching Ants" selection of the Object

[image: marching ants - photoshop]

2. Next click the "New Work Path" button from the "Paths" panel.

[image: Paths Panel] **>>** [image: new work path]

3. Now you can simply use the "Text" tool to create a Text Box

[image: text tool]

The text box will be in the same shape as the "Work Path" (Smart Object)